# Solr Core is not loaded, when I add " spatialContextFactory" attribute in the field type

Tags: java, solr, spatial-query

I am trying to Implement a Solr-Spatial search for polygon , so I have  added

```
spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory"
```

in the file **`schema.xml`** of my core, but after adding this, when I restart my Tomcat, the core is not loaded, and if I don't add the above mentioned attribute it gives error **`"Polygon shape is undefined"`** while searching(But the core is loaded )

From my error logs I am not able to understand what is wrong here, any help would be really appreciated.

**solr.log**

```
   2015-04-16T21:16:02,526 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrResourceLoader@228] - Adding 'file:/opt/lucidworks/fusion/solr/dih/jts-1.8.0.jar' to classloader
2015-04-16T21:16:02,526 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrResourceLoader@228] - Adding 'file:/opt/lucidworks/fusion/solr/dih/spatial4j-0.4.1.jar' to classloader
2015-04-16T21:16:02,526 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrResourceLoader@228] - Adding 'file:/opt/lucidworks/fusion/solr/dih/solr-dataimporthandler-extras-4.10.1.jar' to classloader
2015-04-16T21:16:02,527 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrResourceLoader@228] - Adding 'file:/opt/lucidworks/fusion/solr/dih/mysql-connector-java.jar' to classloader
2015-04-16T21:16:02,527 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrResourceLoader@228] - Adding 'file:/opt/lucidworks/fusion/solr/dih/solr-dataimporthandler-4.10.1.jar' to classloader
2015-04-16T21:16:02,551 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrIndexConfig@162] - IndexWriter infoStream solr logging is enabled
2015-04-16T21:16:02,554 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrConfig@198] - Using Lucene MatchVersion: 4.10.3
2015-04-16T21:16:02,599 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:SolrConfig@317] - Loaded SolrConfig: solrconfig.xml
2015-04-16T21:16:02,603 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:IndexSchema@440] - Reading Solr Schema from /configs/myconf/schema.xml
2015-04-16T21:16:02,654 - INFO  [qtp27984006-16:IndexSchema@468] - [collection1] Schema name=example
2015-04-16T21:16:02,930 - ERROR [qtp27984006-16:SolrException@142] - null:java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/CoordinateSequenceFactory
```

**`schema.xml`**

```
<fieldType name="location_rpt"   class="solr.SpatialRecursivePrefixTreeFieldType"                spatialContextFactory="com.spatial4j.core.context.jts.JtsSpatialContextFactory "distErrPct="0.025" maxDistErr="0.000009" />
```

Comment: "com.spatial4j.core" changed to "org.locationtech.spatial4j"

Answer (score 2):

As noted here: https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrAdaptersForLuceneSpatial4

you must download the JTS jar and put it in WEB-INF/lib in Solr's war file (or the location where that war file gets unpacked). Declaring it as a `<lib>` does not work.